# Android Retrofit Using In Eclipse

Tags: android

I want to know can we use

- Retrofit

  in Eclipse To develop Android Application?Till now i have not shifted to Android Studio.

Comment: Move to `Android Studio` than

Comment: Even if you can you should not. Eclipse is not longer supported as Android development tool. Migration is almost automatic so nothing stops you

Answer (score 2):

Go to this [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) link and download the Latest Jar

then Go to eclipse and follow the instruction as follows

Recommendation:

- Create a "lib" folder and keep all your jars in the folder.
- Subsequently, add all the jar files in the lib folder into your build
  path by using `Project => Properties => Java Build Path => Libraries
  => Add JAR ...`

After adding Jar you can use Retrofit as in android studio
[more ways to add jar in eclipse](http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-(Java))
I hope this works for you.